# ASP.NET 5 Client Side Depdency Management - Bower

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bower, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying out the new ASP.NET 5 with MVC 6, and I'm using bower to manage all my client-side dependencies. Everything is working fine.

But I have a question: When I add a dependency (let's say jQuery). It adds both the `/dist` and `/src` along with bower configuration files to the `/lib` folder of `wwwroot`. How do I make it include just the compiled source for usage? (So I can reference it in my pages via `/lib/jquery/jquery.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently been playing in this space and following is something that I have tried:

1. Deleted the `.bowerrrc` file to enable installing in the default `bower_components` folder under the project folder rather than under `wwwroor\lib` as anything under `wwwroot` tends to get published.
2. Added `"main-bower-files": "2.9.0"` to `package.json`. This package gets all the files mentioned in the `main` property of each installed package's `bower.json` files.
3. Created a gulp task using the above package

   `gulp.task('copyMainFiles', function () {
       return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), { base: 'bower_components' })
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib'));
   });`
4. Added a `postrestore` step to your application's `project.json` file

   `"scripts": {
       "postrestore": "gulp copyMainFiles",
       "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
   }`
5. Updated my application's `bower.json` to copy files which are not listed in `main` (like some packages do not have min files as main files..ex: jQuery). The following settings are read by `main-bower-files`:

   `"overrides": {
       "jquery": {
           "main": [ "dist/jquery.js", "dist/jquery.min.js" ]
       },
       "hammer.js": {
           "main": [ "hammer.js", "hammer.min.js" ]
       },
       "bootstrap": {
           "main": [
               "./dist/js/bootstrap.js",
               "./dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
               "./dist/css/bootstrap.css",
               "./dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
           ]
       }
   }`
6. Finally had to update the `jquery-validation` package to use `1.14.0` instead of `1.11.1` as the previous version does not `dist` folder and indeed no bower.json...

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change lib directory structure, to be without dist? e.g. bootstrap/css instead bootstrap/dist/css

Comment: Sure, all you need to do is change the folder paths under the `"overrides"` configuration above