# Bower exportsOverride doesn't work on ASP.NET 5 beta7

Tags: bower, asp.net-core

The bower_components folder presented on ASP.NET 5 beta6 and earlier, but starting from beta7 bower_components folder doesn't exist anymore and bower packages  located directly in the wwwroot/libs folder. And seems like this change breaks exportsOverride feature. 
Is it possible to reduce the amount of unnecessary files in the lib folder using exportOverrides or some other approach?

In bower.json I have the following exportsOverride section:

```
  "exportsOverride": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "js": "dist/js/*.*",
      "css": "dist/css/*.*",
      "fonts": "dist/fonts/*.*"
    }
  }
```

in the wwwroot folder I expected to see the only files defined in the exportsOverride as it was in previous versions, but I see everything there:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why it would break exportOverrides, but I can tell you there is a file named .bowerrc in the root of the web project and that file tells bower to put the components under wwwroot/lib. I'm guessing the intent is because whether in dev or production we need to load static resources from below wwwroot. for production perhaps use grunt to to process the needed production files in a different sub folder than lib and then use publishExclude in project.son to leave out un-needed files and folders such as wwwroot/lib during publish.

Comment: Thanks, I see that file and now I can change the default location. But the problem is a little bit deeper. if default folder is wwwroot/lib the bower will put everything it downloads to this folder, but I want to keep there just files  which are the part of package. And even if you add exportsOverride bower will copy everithing to the folder and not just the files defined in exportsOverride as it was in beta6

Comment: Following is one solution you can try:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296565/asp-net-5-client-side-depdency-management-bower/32297547#32297547

Comment: Thank you Kiran, I'll give it a try. Looks like acceptable workaround.

Comment: The issue is not in the ASP.NET or project template itself. The gulp task runner doesn't respect exportsOverride https://github.com/zont/gulp-bower/issues/30. The grunt can do it and gulp - not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized, that the issue is not in the ASP.NET or project template itself. The gulp task runner doesn't respect exportsOverride http://github.com/zont/gulp-bower/issues/30. The grunt can do it and gulp - not :(

Answer (score 3):

Hiya just to add my 2 pence here, I was following this post to the letter http://shellmonger.com/2015/02/28/adding-bootstrap-to-your-empty-asp-net-mvc6-project/ and it wasn't working for me, but the post failed to mention that you have to change the .bowerrc file to something like;

{
    "directory": "bower_components"
}

the default value is

{
    "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}